# Multiline regexp in jEdit custom mode

Tags: regex, highlighting, multiline, jedit

I'm currently creating a language with a friend and I would like to provide a highlighting for it in jEdit.
It's syntax is actually quite simple. The functions can only match this pattern:
 `$function_name(arguments)`

Note that our parser is currently working without closing tag like the C-style semi-column and that we would like to keep this feature.

I created my jEdit mode and (almost) succeeded in highligting my pattern with `<SPAN_REGEXP>`. Here's how I did it:

`<SPAN_REGEXP HASH_CAR="\$" TYPE="KEYWORD3" DELEGATE="ARGS">`

`<BEGIN>\$[A-Za_z0-9_]*\s*\(</BEGIN>`

`<END>)</END>`

`</SPAN_REGEXP>`

But It's not good enough.

Here's what I would like:

- Same color for the entire function skeleton : `$func(   )`
- Special highlighting (already defined within the `ARGS` rules set) for `%content1%` in `$func(%content1%)`
- No highlighting for brackets not following a `$func`
- Authorize alternative multiline syntax like

`$func`

`(`

`args`

`)`

which is for now not highlighted. 
I guessed I needed to change my `<BEGIN>` regexp to accept newlines, but it seems that jEdit is unable to match multiline regexp for highlighting although he does it perfectly for search&replace !

I tried the `(?s)` and `(?m)` flags, the `[\d\D]*` workaround, even `[\r\n]*` but it never works.

So, here are my questions:

- Does anyone know how to match multiline regexp in jEdit modes `<SPAN_REGEXP>` ?
- If not, does anyone have any idea how to do what I need ?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you looked at the other editing modes that come with jedit in the `modes` directory?  I wish you the best on `span_regexp`.  I wrested with that construct and lost, so I can't be of help to you.  Sry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yes I did. Found nothing interesting :/

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the help, the SPAN_REGEXP does not support multi-line regexes. You can of course specify multi-line regexes, but they are only checked against individual lines and thus will then never match. You could post a Feature Request to the Feature Request Tracker of jEdit though if there is none for it yet.